# Deleting nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a profile, and this profile has many `curso`s (courses). I show all the courses a profile has on the `show.html.erb` of this profile.

```
<% for curso in @profile.cursos %>
<li><%=h curso.nome %> - <%=h curso.universidade %><br>
Ingresso em: <%=h curso.ano_ingresso %> - Encerra em: <%=h curso.ano_termino %> 
<li>
<%= button_to 'Delete', { :action => "destroy", :id => curso.id },:confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
```

This way, I'm able to show all the courses a profile has on it's page, but the `button_to delete` just doesn't work. I have tried many things already, but I think I'm lost. Any idea on how I can create a link or a button or anything to delete the courses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your routes file

```
resources :profiles do
    resources :courses
end
```

Then you can just use link_to method

```
<%= link_to "Delete", profile_course_path(profile, course), :method => :delete %>
```

Make sure you are providing the correct variables `profile` and `course`

Then in your courses_controller.rb you need to get the profile.

```
before_filter :get_profile

def get_profile
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id]) if params[:profile_id]
end

def destroy
  @course = Corse.find(params[:id])
  @course.destroy
  redirect_to profile_courses_path(@profile)
end
```

That will take you back to the correct profile url with it's nested courses.

## update

For new courses you can use the following link:

```
<%= link_to "New Course", new_profile_course_path(profile) %>
```

That will take you to the `new` action in the courses controller.

You should read up on nested forms [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: Thansk for the answer!
I guess this will work, but when I click on the delete link now it directs me to the form to create a new course. I don't know if this is because I have on my routes `match '/profiles/:id_profile/cursos', :to => 'cursos#new'`, but without this match I can't create any new course. Any idea?

Comment: just use the routes I set up. Delete that route and check the code for updates with a new course. You want to use nested links.

Comment: Thanks, now I can create the course and I'm getting better the idea.
Made some changes to the link
`<%= link_to "Delete", profile_curso_path(@profile, curso), :method => :delete %>`
it now directs me to the link with cursos/:curso_id, but says there is no route to it. I added mannually a route for the destroy with the match and it works, but following what you said, this is "wrong". Any ideia how I can solve?